# About measuring the thrust of an electric thruster

Tags: ion-thruster, low-thrust

I read in some papers, for example this one: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316444395_Recommended_Practice_for_Thrust_Measurement_in_Electric_Propulsion_Testing

That the best way to measure thrust is to use the pendulum thrust stands, why just not use a simple pendulum with a dynamometer?

If we have a heavy object hanging from a pendulum and we make a small force perpendicular to the weight, it will move and we can measure the force with a dynamometer.

I want to experiment with an ion thruster and measure its thrust and I want to avoid building complex equipment

Comment: Rather than just point to an article and hope that each reader goes there and reads it, it's much better to summarize the method in a few sentences here so people can get the idea. For example, what is a "pendulum thrust stand" and how does it differ from a "simple pendulum with a dynamometer"? *Thanks!*

Comment: The thrust force should be measured in the direction of thrust. If you use a simple pendulum causing a direction error, you measure a smaller thrust than the real value.

Comment: Possibly a better fit for Physics SE?

Comment: You're going to need to build complex equipment. Ion thrusters do not work well (or at all) in an atmosphere. You'll need a large vacuum chamber. The thruster itself is not cheap, nor is the propellant. The thrust is tiny (micronewtons to millinewtons), so measuring that tiny thrust requires very sensitive and hence rather expensive equipment. Developing an ion thruster is not a game for a single person.